# How to get the locust loadtest data to prometheus in the kubernetes cluster environment

Tags: python, kubernetes, microservices, prometheus, locust

We have got microservice application deployed in Kubernetes cluster. We need to run the locust load test tool on the Kubernetes cluster and send the metrics to Prometheus. How to get the locust loadtest data to Prometheus in the Kubernetes cluster environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have metrics sent to prometheus in your service then any load-test will trigger these just like any other rest calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use an exporter like prometheus-locust-exporter: https://github.com/deliveryhero/helm-charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-locust-exporter

You can use Grafana to view metrics.